# How to validate form for AJAX request using gem 'jquery-validation-rails'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

I have **gem 'jquery-validation-rails'** in Gemfile.

Included it in application.js file `//= require jquery.validate`

Then I have function/scripts that adds validation to certain fields, as:

```
// Field names from FORM
function validateCampaignForm(){
   var $form = $('form.user_form');
   $form.validate({
      rules: {
         "user[title]": {required: true, maxlength: 80},
         "user[content]": {required: true, maxlength: 80},

         }
    });
}
// Load
validateCampaignForm();


// Save button on click
$('a.save-form').on('click', function(){
  // should validates field
});
```

Generated HTML Form:

```
<form class="user_form" action="/users/1110212666" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="row">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input class="required" type="text" value="We saved your cart" name="user[title]" id="user_title">
  </div>
  ...other fields....

  <a class="button primary save-form" href="#">Save Settings</a>
</form>
```

## Just for testing, I tried to changed the Save (link), to a submit type button:

And checking the form submission.

```
   $('form.campaign_form').on('submit', function(){
      $('form.campaign_form').valid();
      console.log($('form.campaign_form').valid()); // returns TRUE not false even fields with validations are empty
      return false; // just to prevent normal form submission
   });
```

Comment: You can directly add .validate function instead of writting it in separate function. try to add this code in document ready event

Comment: You haven't added `user_form` class on form, to which validation will be called. please check the given answer below and let me know for further guidance.

Comment: `Save settings` won't submit form as it's not submit button.

Comment: @Gabbar yes button is not `submit` type, since I will post an AJAX request for form submission. Have to validate form fields then do ajax stuff. Thanks.

Comment: @Vishal I tried your suggestion, putting the .validate stuff on the top of ready function, but still cant make the errors show in form.

Comment: @aldrien.h check the console of browser, what error you get ? there must be error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate the need to have a submit button within the form, use `.valid()` to trigger a validation

```
<form class="campaign_form" action="/users/1110212666" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="row">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input class="required" type="text" value="We saved your cart" name="user[title]" id="user_title">
  </div>
  ...other fields....

  # IMPORTANT NOTE: <a> or other elements aside from button type="submit" can only trigger the validation. 
  // <a class="button primary save-form" href="javascript:;">Save Settings</a>
  <button type="submit" class="save-form">Save Settings</button>
</form>
```

Validation using jquery-validate

```
// initializes validation
 $('.user_form').validate({
    rules: {
       "user[title]": {required: true, maxlength: 80},
       "user[content]": {required: true, maxlength: 80}
       }
  });

// on click validation of user form
$('.save-form').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // to prevent form from normal submission
  $('.user_form').valid();
});

// other way (catch on form submission)
$('form.campaign_form').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.user_form').valid();
});
```

Comment: Hi @Gabbar, i tried your answer but still errors on fields doesn't show up.

Comment: @aldrien.h Before test it make sure you have configured jquery-validate gem properly as well as its dependicies. Also make sure you hav added jquery .to test it you can inspect element and check whether there are error label or not?

Comment: both jquery & jquery.validate scripts are loaded. but nothing happens with the required fields in form, should have generated label and adding error class, right? but none :(

Comment: i tried to make another form and it works, means plugin is loaded well, and there's something wrong that needs to figure out in my previous form. Thanks

Comment: Finally got the issue solved, submit type is a must to trigger this validation, simple link won't work. i upvote for the help :)

Comment: @aldrien.h HI, could you edit the answer and make it correct with button, it can be helpful for future so searchers also if you could accept answer. thanks :D

Comment: no problem :) , i updated your answer for future reference.